# how to use Dynamic BaseUrl in Retrofit withhilt

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I'm using retrofit in my project with hilt.
so, i need to get baseUrl from user everytime he came in and call a webservice with that baseUrl.
I create my hilt Module Class with Singleton component, but when application run, baseUrl does'nt change.
how can i fix it?

this is my hilt module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Prefs.AppSetting.BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create()
            )
            .build()
    }

}
```

this is my constant:

```
object Prefs {

    object AppSetting {
        var BASE_URL: String = ""
    }
}
```

and finally, it's my compose function:

```
@Composable
fun ConnectionScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: ServerMetaViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val context = LocalContext.current
val uiState: State<ServerInfoState> by lazy {
        viewModel.serverInfoUiState
    }
val urlState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val onCheckServerClick: () -> Unit = {
        Log.i("TAG_APP", "ConnectionScreen: ${urlState.value}")
        Prefs.AppSetting.BASE_URL = ComposeUtils.toUrl(urlState.value)
        viewModel.getServerInfo(urlState.value)
}

Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        UrlTextField(state = urlState, label = "Url")
        FullWidthButton(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            label = "Check Server",
            enabled = ComposeUtils.isValidUrl(urlState.value) && !uiState.value.isLoading,
            onClick = onCheckServerClick
        )
        if (uiState.value.isLoading) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

            CircularProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
    )
  }
}

 uiState.value.errors?.let {
        it.forEach { error ->
            Toast.makeText(context, error.description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

uiState.value.data?.let { 
      Prefs.AppSetting.BASE_URL = urlState.value
      navController.navigatePopUpTo(Destinations.Login.route)
}
```